# Page views count decreases when i select page path as dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I am using google Analytic`s in my product to calculate page views. I am facing a problem. When i call GA API with only **ga:source** as a dimension the count is 7176 but when i add **ga:pagePath** in dimension, the count is decreased.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, page path is when visitors click the full url of your site to browse it.
Source, on the other hand, applys when visitors enter your website after a google search of your site, or one of your pages AND those who added the full url.
So, it is logical that the ga:source is greater than ga:pagePath

Comment: but every source come using a page path.